# Problem with ID mask and glow effect

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I've tried numerous answers on this forum and tutorials, but for some reason I can't get this light to hide properly and still perform a glow effect.  What I need is for the light (highlighted with a green rectangle) to hide properly, but still allow the blur and glare effect to show in the foreground.

Here is a screenshot of the node setup in the compositor:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: my attempt at LukeD's answer for reference.

[image]

Comment: Check my fresh answer from here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88584/creating-a-planet-atmosphere-blurry-edge/88602#88602

Comment: Thanks @LukeD!  However, I wasn't able to achieve that effect.  I've posted my revised node setup based on your solution.  Could you tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First method (recommended):

This one is pretty simple, you can use **Z-Depth** value to 'hide' layer (yellow) behind mesh.

[image: first]

### Second method (with manual Glare control):

If you for some reason would like to hide **Glare** effect from the front part of the mesh you could use **Mask** and manually place it on your image.

[image: second]

Comment: That did it!  The first method was exactly what I was trying to achieve.  Thanks again!