# Z Combining a blurred/glared render layer

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have 2 render layers, one with the main object and one with a particle field (volume). If merged, the main object would be somewhere in the middle of the particle field. This means that some particles are in front of the main object and some are behind it.

Now I'd like to do some glare and blurring on the particles and then Z combine them with the main render layer. However, glare is not visible for some reason. If I disable "Use Alpha" on the Z Combine node, not even blur appears to be working.

Current node setup and result, neither of the glare nodes has any effect on the composite:
[image: Current setup]

With "Use Alpha" turned off:
[image: No use alpha]

Could I achieve the same by using one render layer and object ID masks?

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88613/problem-with-id-mask-and-glow-effect/88662#88662

Comment: Glare adds glare and removes transparency. Instead of AlphaOver node after Glare in your setup use MixRGB node set to Add to add glareto your setup (which is what glare and light does), then areas with glare present will be added on top of the image and black areas after Glare will just add nothing (something + 0)

Comment: @Mr Zak The problem is lack of glare on particles, not so much on the main object

Comment: @MrZak That alpha > Z connection slipped my checks, whoops. Fixed the post, the problem is still present.